# How to check how many participants are connected to my chat room using socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Here is an excerpt of the code I am using to make a connection to my chat room...

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var col = db.collection('messages');
    sendStatus = function(s){
        socket.emit('status', s);
    };
    //emit all messages
    col.find().limit(100).sort({_id:1}).toArray(function(err, res){
        if(err) throw err;
        socket.emit('output', res);

    });
    socket.on('input', function(data) {
    ...
    ... etc
```

What code can I implement to check how many users or participants are connected to my chat room.

I heard of a method `clients()` but I'm not sure if that's what I need to use or how to use it.

Comment: @JordanHendrix - The code in that answer does not appear to work any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version of socket.io, you can see how many sockets are in a given chat room with this:

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms["testRoom"].length
```

Where `testRoom`is whatever the name of your chat room is (whatever you used `.join()` with.

---

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms["testRoom"]
```

is an Object where each property name except `.length` is the socket.id of the socket that is in the chat room.

---

FYI, the code you show in your question doesn't appear to have anything to do with socket.io chat rooms so that has me a bit perplexed.